# How do I import a KML route into OsmAnd?

Tags: maps, osmand

I created a route using **Google Maps** and exported it as a KML file. I would like to import now this KML file into **OsmAnd** so I could check where I am.

So far I found out that it is possible to create a map from a KML file with theOsmAndMapTileCreator program. However, I cannot find one, all I have is OsmAndMapCreator -- and this program does not allow me to import KML in the first place (at least I don't see such option at all). Thus, I cannot prepare a map for OsmAnd (from KML; in general I prepared regular OSM map for OsmAnd using this program).

Since I didn't find any working solution with true off-line KML route imported, I use Google Maps with a pre-loaded route. There is a catch though - if I forget it is cached, and I switch anything in Google Maps I will lose this route when biking. So it is not reliable enough -- just workaround.

The bottom line is -- I have KML file, I have OsmAnd, I would like to import the former into the latter. How do I do it?

Comment: Sorry, but arbitrary bolding and italicizing make posts **harder** to read. There is no reason to do it all over the place like you did, especially having an entire paragraph in italics. People are perfectly capable of reading and understanding normally formatted text just fine, but if you're going to use formatting at least try to be a little judicious. Please also refrain from posting commentary/discussion in your question.

Comment: @eldarerathis, "arbitrary bolding and italicizing make posts harder to read" -- any hard data to back up this statement?

Comment: I don't know about "hard facts" but it's generally accepted convention to avoid using large areas of italics since it doesn't aid the reader (it's not marking key phrases, it's purely stylistic) and it's often particularly more difficult for visually impaired individuals to read. [One opinion](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6824/what-are-your-thoughts-on-using-italics-for-primary-navigation-in-a-page-header), [second opinion](http://www.textmatters.com/resources/pdfs/visImpd_typogTM.pdf)...

Comment: ...and [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography#Readability_and_legibility): "Regular upright type (roman type) is found to be more legible than italic type". I wouldn't be surprised if there's scientific research regarding this, but you might have to pay for the info since many researchers and publications require subscriptions or other fees.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I almost forgot about my own question, meanwhile I found perfectly working solution -- simply converting KML into GPX with GPSBabel: http://www.gpsbabel.org/

It is open source, which is great plus for me.

Comment: Does your resulting .gpx have accurate trackpoints every few meters or is it very sparse (containing only basic turn-by-turn points and such)? I thought this might be the case with Google's regular kml export.

Comment: @ce4, I am not an expert, however I went on a ride on my bicycle and I was 100% fine with me. It helped me navigate in  forest (almost no marks on trees), and on regular roads.

Comment: I'm OK with this answer! Seems like the default export is accurate enough or Osmand handles it just fine (by locking the the missing parts of the route to its internal database ways). I'll try it myself and post my findings...

Answer (score 2):

I use [GMap2GPX](http://www.elsewhere.org/journal/gmaptogpx/).

It loads some JavaScript into the running tab to do all the work. It's fairly easy to use, just follow the instructions on the site.  Use "extract full" to generate a reasonably accurate .gpx file (the basic file just has turn-by-turn instructions and little data besides).

Note: Only use it in an incognito instance for added privacy. You must not be logged into Google using Chrome (or it won't work for security reasons). Just launch an incognito instance via "ctrl+shift+N" and do it again there.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/) and [OpenData plugin](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/OpenData#Installation). To install it just go to preferences(F12)->plugins->search "opendata" and install. After importing you can (as far as I know) save it as *.osm, and then use OsmandMapCreator

Answer (score 1):

Since osmand is about offline maps, I'd like to provide an "offline" solution as well.  Basically, you want to convert the kml file to gpx format, and make the gpx file available to osmand.

You can use gpsbabel to convert the kml file to gpx, which is free/open-source, and is available for most platforms, and is probably in the main repository of your favourite linux distro.  On linux, it's as easy as running the following command, changing out file.kml and file.gpx for your filenames:

```
gpsbabel -i kml -f file.kml -o gpx -F file.gpx
```

You can then put the gpx file in the `/sdcard/osmand/tracks/` directory on your Android device, and osmand will make it available to display, etc.

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer from three years prior

Comment: That response did not provide an example command or tell where to put the resulting file.  I.e., it was incomplete, and since I had to work out the rest on my own I figured I would record the results for others.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried Globalmapper v17 to convert KML to GPX.
How to do:
Open KML file in Globalmapper. 
Then go to "File > Export > Export vector/lidar format"
Change options as needed.
Save to a desired directory.